# Sorting papers by temporal criteria from same authors and different years in the Reference part

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style

I am writing a paper and I found the next problem: I have 6 papers from the same authors (Brocas and Carrillo) and from different years. The code of the .bib is like that:

```
@article{brocas2018determinants,
  title={The determinants of strategic thinking in preschool children},
    author={Brocas, Isabelle and Carrillo, Juan D.},
  journal={PLoS ONE},
  volume={13},
  number={5},
  pages={e0195456},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Public Library of Science San Francisco, CA USA}
}


@article{brocas2020introduction,
  title={Introduction to special issue “Understanding Cognition and Decision Making by Children.” Studying decision-making in children: Challenges and opportunities},
   author={Brocas, Isabelle and Carrillo, Juan D.},
  journal={Journal of Economic Behavior \& Organization},
  volume={179},
  pages={777--783},
  year={2020a},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}



@article{brocas2020iterative,
  title={Iterative dominance in young children: Experimental evidence in simple two-person games},
    author={Brocas, Isabelle and Carrillo, Juan D.},
  journal={Journal of Economic Behavior \& Organization},
  volume={179},
  pages={623--637},
  year={2020b},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}




@article{brocas2020evolution,
  title={The evolution of choice and learning in the two-person beauty contest game from kindergarten to adulthood},
    author={Brocas, Isabelle and Carrillo, Juan D.},
  journal={Games and Economic Behavior},
  volume={120},
  pages={132--143},
  year={2020c},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}



@article{brocas2021steps,
  title={Steps of reasoning in children and adolescents},
   author={Brocas, Isabelle and Carrillo, Juan D.},
  journal={Journal of Political Economy},
  volume={129},
  number={7},
  pages={2067--2111},
  year={2021a},
  publisher={The University of Chicago Press Chicago, IL}
}


@article{brocas2021dynamic,
  title={Dynamic coordination in efficient and fair strategies: a developmental perspective},
   author={Brocas, Isabelle and Carrillo, Juan D.},
  year={2021b},
    howpublished = {CEPR Discussion Paper No. DP16683},
  publisher={CEPR Discussion Paper No. DP16683}
}
```

---

Also, the code of bibliography that I am using is the next one:

```
\usepackage[style=apa, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

---

As you see, I need the bibliography sort in APA format and by author and years of publication. The thing is that when I compile the bibliography with `\printbibliography` I obtain the next:

[image: Bibliography]

---

So the sort of this bibliography is chaotic and I have no idea which criteria my overleaf is following. Please, could anyone help me with this topic?? I assure you that I searched on different blogs and I have tried everything I found and anything changed or improved... Thank you so much in advance. It is kind of urgent because I have to finish writing this paper and this is the last thing I have to do...

Kind regards,

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: It's a mistake to put letters -- e.g., "2021a" -- directly into the `year` field.

Comment: If you look at `biber`'s output, you'll notice quite a few warning messages of the type "WARN - legacy year field '2020a' in entry 'brocas2020introduction' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly." Did you not look at biber's output?

Answer (score 0):

As far as `biber` is concerned, it's a mistake to enter non-numeric characters, such as `a` and `b`, into the `year` field. Sure enough, `biber` sends out messages such as

> "WARN - legacy year field '2020a' in entry 'brocas2020introduction' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly."

You ignore `biber` warning messages at your own peril.

What to do? Just enter instructions such as `\noopsort{a}` and `\noopsort{b}` -- where `\noopsort` is defined as `\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}`, i.e., it outputs nothing -- at the start of the respective `title` fields.

Incidentally, it's incorrect to use the `@article` entry type for entry `brocas2021dynamic`; you should be using the entry type `@techreport` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{} % a special "do nothing" macro

% create a bib file "on the fly":
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@article{brocas2018determinants,
  title  ={The determinants of strategic thinking in preschool children},
  author ={Brocas, Isabelle and Carrillo, Juan D.},
  journal={PLoS ONE},
  volume ={13},
  number ={5},
  pages  ={e0195456},
  year   ={2018},
  publisher={Public Library of Science San Francisco, CA USA}
}

@article{brocas2020introduction,
  title  ={\noopsort{a}{Introduction} to special issue ``{Understanding} 
           Cognition and Decision Making by Children.'' {Studying} 
           decision-making in children: Challenges and opportunities},
  author ={Brocas, Isabelle and Carrillo, Juan D.},
  journal={Journal of Economic Behavior \& Organization},
  volume ={179},
  pages  ={777--783},
  year   ={2020},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{brocas2020iterative,
  title  ={\noopsort{b}{Iterative} dominance in young children:  
           {Experimental} evidence in simple two-person games},
  author ={Brocas, Isabelle and Carrillo, Juan D.},
  journal={Journal of Economic Behavior \& Organization},
  volume ={179},
  pages  ={623--637},
  year   ={2020},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{brocas2020evolution,
  title  ={\noopsort{c}{The} evolution of choice and learning in the 
           two-person beauty contest game from kindergarten to adulthood},
  author ={Brocas, Isabelle and Carrillo, Juan D.},
  journal={Games and Economic Behavior},
  volume ={120},
  pages  ={132--143},
  year   ={2020},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{brocas2021steps,
  title  ={\noopsort{a}{Steps} of reasoning in children and adolescents},
  author ={Brocas, Isabelle and Carrillo, Juan D.},
  journal={Journal of Political Economy},
  volume ={129},
  number ={7},
  pages  ={2067--2111},
  year   ={2021},
  publisher={The University of Chicago Press Chicago, IL}
}

@techreport{brocas2021dynamic,
  title ={\noopsort{b}{Dynamic} coordination in efficient and 
          fair strategies: A developmental perspective},
  author={Brocas, Isabelle and Carrillo, Juan D.},
  year  ={2021},
  type  ={CEPR Discussion Paper},
  number={16683},
  xpublisher={CEPR Discussion Paper No. DP16683}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex} % no need for option 'sorting=nyt'
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{brocas2018determinants,
      brocas2021steps,
      brocas2021dynamic,
      brocas2020introduction,
      brocas2020iterative,
      brocas2020evolution}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```